# CollectionViewCell in TableViewCell didn't retrieve related data in swift3?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift3, uitableview

Home.swift

In my TableViewCell data retrieve data from CoreData ,

```
func getMainHomeTheme(){
        let entityDescription = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "MainThemeHome")
        do{
            let results = try context.fetch(entityDescription)

            if(results.count) > 0 {


                sections.removeAll()

                for i in 0 ..< (results.count){
                    let match = results[i] as! NSManagedObject
                   // let provider_ID = match.value(forKey: "providerID") as! Int
                    main_associated_url = match.value(forKey: "main_associated_url") as! String
                    main_created_by = match.value(forKey: "main_created_by") as! Bool
                    main_created_date = match.value(forKey: "main_created_date") as! String
                    main_description = match.value(forKey: "main_description_") as! String
                    main_name = match.value(forKey: "main_name") as! String
                    main_poster_image_url = match.value(forKey: "main_poster_image_url") as! String
                   // let provider_id = match.value(forKey: "provider_id") as! Int
                    main_modify_by = match.value(forKey: "main_modify_by") as! Bool
                    main_modify_date = match.value(forKey: "main_modify_date") as! String
                    main_status = match.value(forKey: "main_status") as! Bool
                    //  let screen_id = match.value(forKey : "screen_id") as! Bool

                    debugPrint(main_associated_url)

                }
                //debugPrint("Count Deatil \(mainHomeThemeTable.count)")

            }else{
                //no WatchLater Data
            }
        }catch{}
    }
```

Data From CoreData show TableViewCell,

```
 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        debugPrint("Home Category Cout \(mainHomeThemeTable.count)")
        return mainHomeThemeTable.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let mainThemeList = mainHomeThemeTable[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
        self.prefs.set(mainThemeList.main_associated_url, forKey: "associated_home_url")

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "homecell") as! HomeCategoryRowCell

                     cell.categoryTitle.text = mainThemeList.main_name
            cell.mainAssociatedURL.text = mainThemeList.main_associated_url

            cell.categoryTitle.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17.0)
            cell.collectionView.reloadData()





        return cell
    }
```

After Show TableViewCell data, I set prefs of (associated_home_url), that link data retrieve from Server and show in CollectionViewCell.

HomeCategoryRowCell.swift

```
func getAssetsData(){

    if Reachability().isInternetAvailable() == true {


            associated_url = prefs.value(forKey: "associated_home_url") as! String!


            rest.get(url: StringResource().mainURL + associated_url ,  parma: [ "show_min": "true" ], finished: {(result : NSDictionary, status : Int) -> Void in


                self.assetsTable.removeAll()
                if(status == 200){
                    let data = result["data"] as! NSArray
                    if (data.count>0){
                        for item in 0...(data.count) - 1 {

                            let themes : AnyObject = data[item] as AnyObject
                            let  created = themes["created"] as! String
                            let  assets_id = themes["id"] as! Int
                            let name = themes["name"] as! String
                            var poster_img_url = themes["poster_image_url"] as! String
                            let provider_id = themes["provider_id"] as! Int



                            self.assetsTable.append(AssetsTableItem(created: created,assets_id: assets_id, name: name, poster_image_url: poster_img_url,provider_id: provider_id))

                        }
                    }



                }

            })
    }
}
```

The receive data from Server show in collectionViewCell,

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return assetsTable.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {



        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "videoCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeVideoCell

        let list = assetsTable[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]




        AsyncImageLoader.sharedLoader.imageForUrl(urlString: list.poster_url) { (image, url) -> () in
            DispatchQueue.main.async(){

                cell.movieTitle.text = list.name

                cell.imageView.image = image

            }
        }

        return cell

    }
```

My problem is , TableViewCell prefs data aren't correctly retrieve data in CollectionViewCell. 
How to solve  CollectionViewCell in TableViewCell data display?

Comment: Has anyone this problem? Help me please!